# Ubuntu: Running Memcached as daemon

Tags: ubuntu, memcached, daemon

I have installed `memcached` on Ubuntu. How can I run it as a daemon so that it runs in the background and I can use it in my rails application?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`memcached` is configured to run at boot by default, at least on 10.10:

```
# apt-get install memcached
...
Setting up memcached (1.4.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Starting memcached: memcached.
# ls -l /etc/rc*.d/*memcached
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2011-03-23 13:36 /etc/rc0.d/K20memcached -> ../init.d/memcached
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2011-03-23 13:36 /etc/rc1.d/K20memcached -> ../init.d/memcached
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2011-03-23 13:36 /etc/rc2.d/S20memcached -> ../init.d/memcached
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2011-03-23 13:36 /etc/rc3.d/S20memcached -> ../init.d/memcached
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2011-03-23 13:36 /etc/rc4.d/S20memcached -> ../init.d/memcached
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2011-03-23 13:36 /etc/rc5.d/S20memcached -> ../init.d/memcached
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2011-03-23 13:36 /etc/rc6.d/K20memcached -> ../init.d/memcached
#
```

In runlevels 2, 3, 4, and 5, memcached will be running.

If you're not sure, you can run the initscript with `status`:

```
# /etc/init.d/memcached status
 * memcached is running
```

Comment: I have installed it from source, as I had some problem installing with `apt-get`. Now I have ran is in `daemon mode` using `-d` switch. But `/etc/init.d/memcached status` say `No such file or directory`. However when I try 'memcached status' it say `failed to listen on TCP port 11211: Address already in use`. So it means it's running in background.

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned that you installed from source :) See if there is a contributed initscript in the memcached sources that you can install into `/etc/init.d` and all symlink into the `/etc/rc*.d/` directories as the default packaging provides. (If the memcached source doesn't include an initscript, you might just want to run `cd /tmp; apt-get source memcached` and steal the initscript from the Ubuntu packaging, then edit it to reference wherever you installed your `memcached` executable. It might also need you to create user and group accounts.)

Comment: If you get *permission denied* errors when you enter the install command then remember to add *sudo* before it - *sudo apt-get install memcached*.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else ends up here looking for how to run the daemon directly (like inside a docker container for example).  The flag you're looking for is `-d`.

```
/usr/bin/memcached start -u memcached -d
```

Answer (score 0):

To install memcached on ubuntu

`apt-get install memcached`

To start memcached

`/etc/init.d/memcached start`

To restart memcached

`/etc/init.d/memcached start`

To check the status of memcached

`/etc/init.d/memcached status`

To edit memcached config

`sudo vi /etc/memcached.conf`

By default memcached will run on `127.0.0.1:11211` and is configured to run at boot by default